# There is no JAR file in your CLI for Node.Js. SuiteCloud CLI

Tags: node.js, netsuite, suitecloud

I'm trying to use SuiteCloud CLI with NodeJS but I'm facing an error when running commands:
[image: "There is no JAR File in your CLI for Node.JS. Run "npm install from /usr/lib/node_module/@oracle/suitecloud-cli" to install a JAR file]

I've already found that it was a bug in a older version and should be fixed.
Is there any way to install manually JAR File? Anyone with the same behavior with 1.5.0?

BTW : Using the SuiteCloud extention for VS Code works fine. But it doesn't have all the features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the SUDO command before `suitecloud project:validate` .